# display image.json in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a json type image, if the json image will be displayed on flutter, how do I do it ??
[image].and an error occurs like in the debug console.
is it because I use only displaying json images with this code

```
Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6.3,
              child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo/bang_bana_hitam_putih_150x94.png')),
```

how do I map json type images to appear ??

Comment: JSON is not an image type. Could you post the content of the json file here?so I can understand better what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: There are so many type of image available in code json code , but you have to defined here which kind of code you have for rendor image in your ui. like flr, nima, etc